# Why does the cursor change in PyQt?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a program. When I click on the "Hello" button, my cursor changes (within 5 seconds) (the cursor is the mouse cursor). Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong? Why does my cursor change for five seconds? What can I do to keep the cursor from changing?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QAction, qApp, QApplication, QPushButton,QLabel
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTime, QTimer, Qt, QRect


class Example2(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):

        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):               

        self.statusBar()
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 200)

        btn2 = QPushButton("Cat", self)
        btn2.resize(btn2.sizeHint())
        btn2.move(50,50)

        btn2.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked)

        lbl1 = QLabel("We like it", self)
        lbl1.setGeometry(QRect(50, 30, 150, 50))

        lbl1.setScaledContents(True)
        lbl1.updateGeometry()
        lbl1.adjustSize()

        self.show()

    def buttonClicked(self):
        pass


class Example1(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI() 


    def initUI(self):               

        self.statusBar()
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 200)

        btn1 = QPushButton("Hello", self)
        btn1.resize(btn1.sizeHint())
        btn1.move(50, 85)

        btn1.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked)

        self.show()


    def buttonClicked(self):
        sender = self.sender()
        if sender.text() == 'Hello':

            self.hide()
            self.Example2 = Example2()
            self.Example2.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example1()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

    print("Hello")
```

Comment: What does it change to? What platform are you on?

Comment: I use Ubuntu 16.04 but it does not matter, I decided to use QT5 with C++